# Vanilla Javascript Scroll Animation not working

Tags: javascript

I am creating a simple website and I want to run an animation on the elements whenever I scroll down using javascript and as you can see on my html i added a class called "js-scroll" to all element that i want to animate. Please see my code below. The problem is: I can only animate the text when i scroll. How can I fix this?

```js
window.addEventListener("scroll", () => {
  const header = document.querySelector("header");
  header.classList.toggle("sticky", window.scrollY > 0);
});

const scrollOffset = 100;

const scrollElement = document.querySelector(".js-scroll");

const elementInView = (el, offset = 0) => {
  const elementTop = el.getBoundingClientRect().top;

  return (
    elementTop <=
    (window.innerHeight || document.documentElement.clientHeight) - offset
  );
};

const displayScrollElement = () => {
  scrollElement.classList.add("scrolled");
};

const hideScrollElement = () => {
  scrollElement.classList.remove("scrolled");
};

const handleScrollAnimation = () => {
  if (elementInView(scrollElement, scrollOffset)) {
    displayScrollElement();
  } else {
    hideScrollElement();
  }
};

window.addEventListener("scroll", () => {
  handleScrollAnimation();
});
```

```css
.js-scroll {
  opacity: 0;
  transition: 500ms;
}

.scrolled {
  opacity: 1;
}

.scrolled.slideL {
  animation: slideLeft 1s ease;
}
.scrolled.slideR {
  animation: slideRight 1s ease;
}
.scrolled.down {
  animation: drop 1.5s ease;
}
```

```html
 <body>
    <header>
      <h1 class="logo">DROP</h1>
      <ul class="nav-links">
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Vegetables</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Herbals</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Reviews</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
      </ul>
    </header>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="main-content">
        <h1 class="title">Pick Only The Best</h1>
        <p>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Et, debitis
          aut nam aperiam porro repudiandae architecto ea commodi quisquam
          nostrum.
        </p>
        <a href="#" class="btn">Explore</a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <section class="veggies-showcase">
      <div class="veggies-wrapper">
        <div class="veggies-text js-scroll slideL">
          <h1 class="title">Healthy Vegetables</h1>
          <p>
            Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolores
            voluptate aspernatur tempora sit illum earum qui quod itaque quos
            voluptas non, omnis veniam adipisci. Odit quidem asperiores suscipit
            vitae repudiandae.
          </p>
          <p>
            <br />
            Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Vel ad
            dignissimos at minima culpa. Nulla esse sed dolores voluptatibus.
            Excepturi voluptates deserunt in ipsam omnis molestiae, aspernatur
            magni repudiandae atque?
          </p>
        </div>
        <div class="veggies-img js-scroll slideR">
          <img src="img/bg2.jpg" width="600px" />
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>

    <section class="herbals">
      <div class="herbal-container js-scroll down">
        <div class="herbal-text">
          <h1>Herbal Medicine</h1>
          <p>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Neque
            facilis accusamus minus voluptates, alias necessitatibus cum numquam
            fugit, dolorem doloremque non quos temporibus debitis? Eum nisi id
            dolores doloremque dignissimos.
          </p>
          <br />
          <p>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Autem nam
            dolore commodi earum aliquid et nostrum, libero maiores architecto
            ad quae eius odio unde at accusamus soluta illo vitae vel.
          </p>
          <br />
          <p>
            Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Molestias
            voluptatibus veniam dolorum repellendus dolorem neque fugit facilis
            repudiandae? Non aliquid facilis, eveniet quis dolorem distinctio
            commodi laborum! Dolores, dolorem minus.
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Would using [scrollIntoView](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView) be of any help?

Comment: What is the desired result? It seems to work as expected at the moment.

Comment: my desired result is to run the animation on all of my elements with the class of js-scroll when they are in view. but the only thing that animates when i scroll is the text in the "HEALTHY VEGATBLES" div